# 'make dep' fails due to missing separator?

Tags: linux

i  am installing asterisk server on my laptop with ubuntu16.04. during installation 'make dep' gives following error:

```
for dir in pjlib/build pjlib-util/build pjnath/build third_party/build pjmedia/build pjsip/build pjsip-apps/build ; do \
    if make  -C $dir dep; then \
        true; \
    else \
        exit 1; \
    fi; \
done
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/asterisk-13.16.0/pjproject/pjlib/build'
make -f /usr/src/asterisk-13.16.0/pjproject/build/rules.mak APP=PJLIB app=pjlib depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/usr/src/asterisk-13.16.0/pjproject/pjlib/build'
.pjlib-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.depend:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/asterisk-13.16.0/pjproject/pjlib/build'
Makefile:88: recipe for target 'depend' failed
make[1]: *** [depend] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/asterisk-13.16.0/pjproject/pjlib/build'
Makefile:14: recipe for target 'dep' failed
make: *** [dep] Error 1
```

where makefile line 88 and line 14 are(respectively):

```
$(MAKE) -f $(RULES_MAK) APP=PJLIB app=pjlib depend

export PJLIB_SONAME := libpj.$(SHLIB_SUFFIX)
```

what could be the reason???

Answer (score 0):

Make wants to have hard tabs in its makefiles. This seems to be a bug in the asterix sources. Maybe you habe to fill a bugticket. This makefile seems to reside in

```
/usr/src/asterisk-13.16.0/pjproject/pjlib/build.
```

It is named "makefile". You can check this for yourself. The problem is at line 88 of that file.

But building from source usually means only a

```
make configure --prefix=<dir to install>
make
```

I doubt this has been overseen. Maybe just a "make configure; make" is sufficent for your needs